# Криптоанализ числового шифра простой замены

Tags: c#, .net, криптография

Есть зашифрованный текст (прикреплю ниже). Нужно провести криптоанализ: получить исходный текст. Известно, что язык исходного текста - русский. Так же известно, что каждое двузначное число в шифре - это определённая буква. Известно так же то, что символа пробела здесь нет - одни буквы. Зашифрованный текст:

```
60 46 57 46 52, 28 15 57 39 12 32 60 32 32 46 57 52 55 30 12 61 11 55 57 32 12 41, 
37 46 60 37 32 91 52 32 11 55 12 32 75 46 46 57 30 32 20 15 75 46 25 99 20 52 32 
52 52 46 67 55 25 55 12 12 32 12 39 52 19 63 “52 99 57 32 36” 75 46 12 61 28 75 
99 (18 32 37 57 39 52 99 57 32 36 67 46 60 32 25 63 15 99 91 32 57 25 46 60 46 
36 60 19 37 46 57 19 “37 67 99 25 55 12 39 30 25 15 52 46” 67 46 20 32 91 12 32). 
57 55 37 55 91 55 41 67 57 99 28 75 55. 75 25 55 37 55 60 32 74, 37 57 46 99 57 67 
25 99 20 52 55 57 39, 99 20 41 45 52 19 36, 11 12 99 52 52 46 75 25 19 12 19 36, 
37 15 67 32 25 55 29 25 46 11 99 52 55 91 99 28 32 37 75 99 36, 60 19 37 46 57 52 19 36. 
“11 48 99 – 29 25 – 11 60 32 52 55 11 74 55 57 39”, 52 46 60 32 36 18 99 36 37 55 91 46 
12 32 57 29 12 32 75 57 25 46 52 52 46 36 25 55 20 60 32 11 75 99, 46 37 52 55 45 32 52 
52 19 36 55 67 67 55 25 55 57 15 25 46 36, 78 46 25 11 46 99 91 32 52 15 32 91 46 36 
“57 32 63 52 99 75 46 36 11 60 55 11 74 55 57 39 67 32 25 60 46 78 46 60 32 75 55” 
(63 46 57 41 11 46 75 46 52 74 55 11 60 55 11 74 55 57 46 78 46 37 57 46 12 32 57 99 41, 
37 46 78 12 55 37 52 46 63 25 46 52 46 12 46 78 99 99, 46 37 57 55 12 46 37 39 32 45 32 
67 41 57 52 55 11 74 55 57 39 37 12 99 18 52 99 91 12 32 57)…
```

Я провёл частотный анализ текста и получил некоторые результаты. Количество букв всего - 403, их частоты (в скобках указано количество символов в тексте):

```
46 - 0.1092 (44)
32 - 0.0868 (35)
55 - 0.0819 (33)
57 - 0.0744 (30)
52 - 0.0744 (30)
99 - 0.0596 (24)
12 - 0.0496 (20)
37 - 0.0471 (19)
25 - 0.0471 (19)
11 - 0.0372 (15)
60 - 0.0372 (15)
36 - 0.0347 (14)
75 - 0.0323 (13)
67 - 0.0273 (11)
39 - 0.0223 (9)
91 - 0.0223 (9)
19 - 0.0223 (9)
15 - 0.0174 (7)
41 - 0.0149 (6)
74 - 0.0149 (6)
20 - 0.0149 (6)
63 - 0.0124 (5)
78 - 0.0124 (5)
28 - 0.0099 (4)
18 - 0.0074 (3)
45 - 0.0074 (3)
29 - 0.0074 (3)
30 - 0.0074 (3)
61 - 0.005 (2)
48 - 0.0025 (1)
```

После этого, я взял из интернета общие статистические данные частот букв русского языка:

```
О - 0.090, Е - 0.072, А - 0.062, И - 0.062, Т - 0.053,
Н - 0.053, С - 0.045, Р - 0.040, В - 0.038, Л - 0.035,
К - 0.028, М - 0.026, Д - 0.025, П - 0.023, У - 0.021,
Я - 0.018, Ы - 0.016, З - 0.016, Ь - 0.014, Б - 0.014,
Г - 0.013, Ч - 0.012, Й - 0.010, Х - 0.009, Ж - 0.007,
Ю - 0.006, Ш - 0.006, Ц - 0.004, Щ - 0.003, Э - 0.003,
Ф - 0.002
```

И попробовал сопоставить полученные данные мною и данные частот букв русского языка. Но получилась какая-то белиберда (пример до первой точки):

```
Л О И О Т, Х З И Ы С Е Л Е Е О И Т А Ж С Щ К А И Е С Ь,
В О Л В Е Я Т Е К А С Е Д О О И Ж Е Б З Д О Р Н Б Т Е
Т Т О П А Р А С С Е С Ы Т У Ч "Т Н И Е М" Д О С Щ Х Д
Н (Ю Е В И Ы Т Н И Е М П О Л Е Р Ч З Н Я Е И Р О Л О
М Л У В О И У "В П Н Р А С Ы Ж Р З Т О" П О Э Б Е Я С Е).
```

Сделал это всё на C#. Примерный код, написанный на коленке:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, double> symbols = new Dictionary<string, double>()
    {
        ["О"] = 0.090,
        ["Е"] = 0.072,
        ["А"] = 0.062,
        ["И"] = 0.062,
        ["Т"] = 0.053,
        ["Н"] = 0.053,
        ["С"] = 0.045,
        ["Р"] = 0.040,
        ["В"] = 0.038,
        ["Л"] = 0.035,
        ["К"] = 0.028,
        ["М"] = 0.026,
        ["Д"] = 0.025,
        ["П"] = 0.023,
        ["У"] = 0.021,
        ["Я"] = 0.018,
        ["Ы"] = 0.016,
        ["З"] = 0.016,
        ["Ь"] = 0.014,
        ["Б"] = 0.014,
        ["Г"] = 0.013,
        ["Ч"] = 0.012,
        ["Й"] = 0.010,
        ["Х"] = 0.009,
        ["Ж"] = 0.007,
        ["Ю"] = 0.006,
        ["Ш"] = 0.006,
        ["Ц"] = 0.004,
        ["Щ"] = 0.003,
        ["Э"] = 0.003,
        ["Ф"] = 0.002
    };

    private static string Decrypt(string encryptText)
    {
        string result = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptText)) return result;
        var temp = encryptText.Split(' ');
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (string s in temp)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(s))
            {
                dict.Add(s, 0);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            dict[temp[i]]++;
        }

        var myList = dict.ToList();
        myList.Sort((pair1, pair2) => pair2.Value.CompareTo(pair1.Value));

        Console.WriteLine($"Encrypt text:\n{encryptText}\n");

        Console.WriteLine($"Symbols count - {temp.Length}");

        foreach (var kv in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} - {Math.Round((double)kv.Value / temp.Length, 4)} ({kv.Value})");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        result = encryptText;

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            var symbol = symbols.ElementAt(i);

            result = result.Replace(myList[i].Key, symbol.Key);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Decrypt text:\n{result}");

        return result;
    }
```

Предположил, что так как текста немного, то и последовательность не обязательна будет соблюдаться строго. Что посоветуете сделать? Или возможно у кого-то выйдет расшифровать? Я был бы признателен любой помощи.

Comment: Ну вы бы какой-нибудь код приложили, чтобы проще было экспериментировать с вашими данными. Задача интересная, но писать код с нуля как-то не хочется.

Comment: А так то да, частоты букв в разных текстах могут идти в разном порядке, а если текст небольшой, то возможны сильные отклонения от типичной статистики.

Comment: @CrazyElf, Добавил код. Писалось быстро да небрежно, поэтому не обессудьте. Здесь просто сопоставлялось место двузначного числа в списке со списком символов в Dictionary.

Comment: Так, а что это за одинокая `4`: `46 4 20`??

Comment: @CrazyElf, проверил исходный зашифрованный текст. По всей видимости, это опечатка. Исправил текст и частоты соответственно.

Comment: А что нужно сделать-то? Просто расшифровать текст или написать программу, которая выдаст исходный текст?

Comment: @Эникейщик, просто расшифровать текст.

Comment: если надо просто расшифровать, то [забиваем в гугле](https://www.google.com/search?q=60+46+57+46+52), получаем [ответ](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cryptography/thread1012690.html). Специально не пишу текст  сюда на случай, если кто хочет самостоятельно его найти.

Comment: @tym32167, до этого я не додумался. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется надо начинать не с этого. По правилам русского языка, запятая после первого слова ставится в 2-х случаях:

1. Вводное слово/выражение
2. Обращение

В данном случае мы имеем первое слово/выражение из 5 букв: `60 46 57 46 52`, в котором 2-е и 4-я буквы совпадают. Берем [список вводных слов/выражений](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-alphabet) и понимаем, что этому условию не удовлетворяет ни одно из них.

Остается вариант обращения. Берем список имен ([пока русских](https://kakzovut.ru/russkie-imena.html) и видим что критерию удовлетворяют несколько имен: ЗАХАР, ЛИДИЯ, МАКАР и т.д. Отметим, что частоты `И` и `А` вполне укладываются в частоты появления символа `46`

Второе вводное слово/выражение/обращение `75 25 55 37 55 60 32 74` из 7 букв, можно провести аналогичный анализ.

Как то так. Надеюсь натолкнул на мысли.

Comment: По правилам русского языка запятыми выделяются разные обороты. В предложении "А овод, кружа вокруг цветка, целился в его середину" нет ни обращения, ни вводного оборота, однако есть запятая.

Comment: Обожаю таких кэпов, если вы не поняли, речь шла об идее :) но за *АОВОД* спасибо :)

Comment: @Barmaley, ответ был найден. И если Вам интересно, на самом деле, там находится фраза "Вот он". Не обращение и не вводное слово/выражение.

Comment: Если вы не поняли о чем речь, то ни один из ваших двух вариантов (вводное слово или обращение) тут не подходит. PS. АОВОД это два слова. Ваш кэп. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Кэп, в исходном тексте, согласно условиям пробелов нет, так что `АОВОД` прекрасно подходит :)

Comment: В моем тексте пробелы есть. Поэтому непонятно, с чего вы вдруг придумали себе этот АОВОД. Ну коль нравится - пользуйтесь. Дарю.